# Redirecting from www.host.com to host.com in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Can someone please provide me with the proper directives in .htaccess file to have www.host.com requests to be redirected to host.com and vice versa?

Comment: @BusterX welcome and please do use the search before starting a new question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430617/how-to-redirect-www-url-to-non-www-url-with-htaccess

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659949/how-to-change-htaccess-to-redirect-all-non-www-links-to-www-pages

Comment: Unfortunately, .htaccess questions have been determined to be barely on-topic.

Comment: @Prix, I do not think these would work for me, I need to only strip www subdomain off, rest of the subdomains should remain. For example, test.example.com will remain the same while www.example.com will be converted to example.com

Comment: @BusterX that is called lack of information, when a question is not well made. Either way for hte 1st example you could simple do: `RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]`

Answer (score 2):

This will redirect from http://www.yoursite.com to http://yoursite.com:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yoursite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

And this is the reverse:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above is what I use on my server, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not sure if these would work. I want any other subdomain to work, for example test.yoursite.com should remain the same, only www.yoursite.com needs to be stripped